# React: Add user inputted form data to current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation, state, setstate

I'm working on a React project that has a form input. I want the user to enter a number in the input field and then I want to take that number and add it to a number in state.

i.e. this.state.data contains the number 5, the user inputs the number 10 in the form, and this.state.data updates to 15.

How can I do this? Everything I've tried so far concatenates the new value to the older value and I end up with 510 instead of 15.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: '5'
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.state.data);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data + e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.data}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Here is a Codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-tharp-0pi7b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is that you are concatenating two strings. You have `this.state.data` initially set to 5 in a string and the user input is also a string. This is tricky since JavaScript is a loosely-typed language. If you want to add the numbers together (5 + 10 = 15). You can do this:

1. Initially set `this.state.data` to 5 without quotes so it is a number
2. You should have another variable in state called something like `input`. In your `handleChange` method, you should just update this to `e.target.value`.
3. In your `handleSubmit`, you would then convert `this.state.input` to a number and then add it with `this.state.data`. This should get you your answer.

Comment: Wow this was one of the dumber mistakes I've made recently. Thanks for the help, definitely a facepalm moment for me.

Answer (score 1):

you initialed the Data state with '5' and it's String typed,
change it to 5 and check the result.

```
 this.state = {
  data: 5
};
```